# How do I get Approved to use the restricted LinkedIn Connections API

Tags: flutter, rest, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I want to be able to get the first-degree connections of an authorized user and import them into my mobile app.

How do I get Linkedin to give me access to their restricted APIs??

I tried to use the Connections API, but I got an error saying:

```
    "Not enough permissions to access: GET-viewer /connections"
```

I need to have these scopes added to my app:

- r_1st_connections
- r_compliance

Comment: Isn't this a question for LinkedIn?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to be able to get the connections of an authorized user and import them into my app

Comment: refer the answer given for similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73456539/2923156