# How do I get Approved to use the restricted LinkedIn Connections API?

Tags: api, rest, oauth, linkedin-api

I want to be able to get the first-degree connections of an authorized user and import them into my mobile app.

How do I get Linkedin to give me access to their restricted APIs??

I tried to use the Connections API, but I got an error saying:

```
"Not enough permissions to access: GET-viewer /connections"
```

I need to have these scopes added to my app:

- r_1st_connections
- r_compliance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Linkedin Developer Support:
"Unfortunately we cannot grant access to the connections API, this endpoint is part of our compliance API, which is only granted to partners who are helping Regulated LinkedIn Members and Customers facilitate regulatory compliant usage of Social Media. (i.e.- it exists solely for monitoring and auditing activity where such monitoring/auditing is legally required by the SEC)." Hence, the permission error.".

Comment: How you are able to communicate with "From Linkedin Developer Support"? Can you please share the link from where we can ask questions to the Linkedin support team? I am also struggling with one weird issue and need urgent help there.

Comment: You can communicate with LinkedIn here: https://linkedin.zendesk.com/

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have created a linkedin App, if not then create it from here https://developer.linkedin.com/

Then you need to apply for LinkedIn product **"Marketing Developer Platform"**. It takes 4-5 working days to get approval from linkedin team.

[image]

**Once you get access to this, it will allow you to use the auth scope**

```
r_1st_connections_size
Use your 1st-degree connections' data
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have done all these above. 

I have been given access to the "Marketing Developer Platform" and "r_1st_connections_size". However, these only return the total number of connections of a user.

I want to be able to get the details of each connection, like name, email, etc. So that the authorized user can import them as contacts into my app.

How do I go about that??